# Find out if changes were pushed to origin in gitpython

Tags: gitpython

In shell I say 'git status' and get output:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

or

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
```

In GitPython how can I find out if changes have not been not pushed to remote yet?

Comment: I too am interested in the answer to this question, if it is possible to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no wrapper for this functionality yet (I searched for one myself and stumbled upon your answer). But what you can do is [use git directly](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly).

Depending on how complicated you want your solution to be, a quick way might be to do the following:

```py
import re
from git import Repo

a_repo = Repo("/path/to/your/repo")
ahead = 0
behind = 0

# Porcelain v2 is easier to parse, branch shows ahead/behind
repo_status = a_repo.git.status(porcelain="v2", branch=True)

ahead_behind_match = re.search(r"#\sbranch\.ab\s\+(\d+)\s-(\d+)", repo_status)
# If no remotes exist or the HEAD is detached, there is no ahead/behind info
if ahead_behind_match:
    ahead = int(ahead_behind_match.group(1))
    behind = int(ahead_behind_match.group(2))

print("Repo is {} commits ahead and {} behind.".format(ahead, behind))
```